# How to locate graphic <canvas> html element for scraping?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm currently scraping a website dedicated to money conversion using python and library selenium, for that case I need to extract the information received by a graphic which shows the money value hourly, but I've been unable to find where is the function on the  component or part of the html scripts that can help me extracting that information.

This is the link to the website: https://dolar.set-icap.com/

Comment: I believe you mean scraping, not scrapping

Comment: Please specify which python library are you using to scrape the web page.